# How to split a single MP3 files into multiple ones based on a tracklist?

Tags: audio, mp3, splitter

I have an MP3 file which has in it the entire soundtrack of a game. I have a list which has the tracks with the titles and the time from which it starts. How can I conveniently split the single track into individual ones based on the list?

Is there any software that allows for achievement of the same?

The format of the list is:

```
#:## <Track 1>
#:## <Track 2>
```

where `#` represents a decimal digit. Although I have some programming skills so I shall be able to transform it into a different format if needed. But what software would actually utilize the list?

Thanks in anticipation of your response.

Comment: You could use s cue sheet. Its likely that you can edit the tracklist and transform it into a cuesheet manually by using a text editor. The question is if this is sufficient.

Comment: @LPChip I need to be able to actually output separate files. I don't think using cue sheets would help me get that :3

Comment: @LPChip Nice idea with the cue file though... I found something as well -> https://jdrch.wordpress.com/2013/11/13/how-to-split-an-mp3-using-a-cue-file-on-windows-without-re-encoding-or-using-medieval-cue-splitter/

Comment: Well, then you really do need software, which makes this question off-topic for SuperUser.

Comment: @LPChip Are questions seeking software recommendations off topic here? I'm not much familiar with the Super User community....

Comment: Yes they are. See the Help Center for how to ask a question and what is considered on-topic.

Comment: LPChip Thanks... I probably had gone through that stuff and the tour... But all the while I had the conception that anything software or hardware related questions were welcome. :) Never mind...

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you can give https://linux.die.net/man/1/mpgsplit a try.
It accepts ranges which can be expressed as Time Format HH:MM:SS.SS or Offset Format (number of Megabytes or kilobytes). You'll need to adjust your list entries accordingly.

I will write a script following this steps:

- loop the lines of your track list
- build the mpgtx command as a string with interpolated range start/end values taken from every row ##:##. The end value of a track could be the start of the next minus a 1 sec.
- execute the command string via the shell (shell-out)

Please note: mpgsplit is equivalent to `mpgtx -s`

Comment: Does it work on windows?

Comment: I don't have a Window machine here but this looks promising: 
There seems to be a win version, you can try downloading and executing it yourself.
http://prdownloads.sourceforge.net/mpgtx/mpgtx.zip?download

Answer (score 3):

https://sourceforge.net/projects/mp3splt/

its the best free app ive found that lets you split based on silence between songs
i use it for youtube files after downloading and converting with https://yt1s.com/en1

i usually split by silence after 180 seconds per file with half a second of silence

ive also split audio books by silence with 20 minute chapters, based on silence https://www.openculture.com/freeaudiobooks